# What does “systematic” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does “systematic” mean in the sentence below?

> Marzuki Darusman, the Special Rapporteur on the situation of human rights in the DPRK,  told the UN Human Rights Council on March 11<sup>th</sup> that many of the **systematic** patterns of human rights violations documented in the DPRK may constitute crimes against humanity, Mr. Darusman’s latest report provided a comprehensive overview of the human rights situation in the country since the inception of his mandate in 2004.
> <sub>Source: [freeforallblog.org – UN Establishes Commission to Examine Rights Abuses in North Korea](http://www.freeforallblog.org/un-establishes-commission-to-examine-rights-abuses-in-north-korea/)</sub>

Does it mean organized, methodical, or categorized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could indicate that the human rights violations are deliberate and follow an explicit system, but I think more likely it is being used as in [sense 3b in Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/systematic):

> marked by thoroughness and regularity: *systematic* efforts